# MySQL - Updating a selection with iterative integers

Tags: mysql, database, algorithm, optimization, bigdata

**Hello again internet nerds!**

*Technically* I have solved this problem, but want to know if there is a more optimal route I should take...

I have a large table (~4m rows) that is a collection of data, segmented using int "chip." There are 6 segments of data, so Chip IDs 1 through 6.

Of these 6 segments, I need to assign an **order** integer, which needs to be iterative, as it represents the exact location of the data on said segment.

My solution is (was) this:

```
# set iterative
set @i:=0;

# init
update table set `order` = @i:=(@i+1) where chip = 1;
```

**This works**. But it is so slow it *sometimes* triggers a timeout error. I need to run it 6 times and it may be triggered on occasion by our application whenever necessary. Maybe it's just that I need to alot more time to MySQL settings to account for the slow query, or is there an optimal, simpler solution for this?

Thanks for the advice.

**Edit:**

I've found a solution that works accurately and takes ~50 seconds to complete.

I'm now using an ordered select statement paired in the update, using a generated join table that's iterating within a column.

See:

```
set @count:= 0;
update 
table as target,
    (select 
    (@count :=  @count+1) as row_num,
    t.*
    from table as t
    where chip = 1
    order by t.id asc) as table_with_iterative
set target.`order` = table_with_iterative.row_num
where target.id = table_with_iterative.id;
```

Comment: *This works* Formally it is random ordering. *it is so slow* What is execution time? *is there an optimal, simpler solution for this?* Specify MySQL version and show table's DDL.

Comment: @Akina I guess "so slow" meaning it breaks my default run time of 15 seconds. I expect it must be hovering around that range somewhere. Can I just add a temporary lock_timeout setting to fix? That just feels like a patch to me, but I guess there's nothing wrong doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I think that if possible you should assign the sequence numbers as you are inserting the rows into the table for the very first time.  Strictly speaking, an SQL database does not promise that rows will initially appear inside the table in the order of of the `INSERT` statements.

One possibility that occurs to me is to use an auto-increment field in this table, because this *will* express the order in which the rows were added.  But the field-values for any given `chip`, although ascending, might not be consecutive and undoubtedly would not start at `1`.

If you did need such a field, I think I'd define a separate field (default value: `NULL`) to hold it.  Then, a very simple *stored procedure* could query the rows for a given chip  (`ORDER BY` auto-increment number) and assign a 1-based consecutive sequential number to that separate field.  (A slightly more elaborate query could identify all the lists that don't have those numbers yet, and number all of them at once.)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution that works accurately and takes ~50 seconds to complete.

This handles the out-of-order updates I was experiencing.

I'm now using an ordered select statement paired in the update statement, using a generated join table that's iterating within a column row_num.

See:

```
set @count:= 0;
update 
table as target,
    (select 
    (@count :=  @count+1) as row_num,
    t.*
    from table as t
    where chip = 1
    order by t.id asc) as table_with_iterative
set target.`order` = table_with_iterative.row_num
where target.id = table_with_iterative.id;
```